# What is a good practice for adding flow type annotations on project specific named exports

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

Please correct me if i am wrong. As far as i understand it up till now; type annotations can be added to a file or in libdefs (for shareable code)

For example in a project specific file helpers.js

```
// @flow
export function square(value: number): number {
 return value * value
}

export function someOtherFunction(arg: string): string {
}

etc...
```

And in a libdef helpers.js

```
declare module 'helpers' {
  declare export function square(value: number): number;
  declare export function someOtherFunction(arg: string): string;
}
```

What would be a good practice for writing flow annotations on project specific code and especially lots of code. For example helpers exposing 20+ named exports, as this is the point where i am starting to think having a libdef would be more clearer to reason about.

And is it at all possible to use that libdef file as the single entry? I've fooled around a bit and i always had to annotate in the file itself even though i had added the libdef and told flow through the config to include these libdefs.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my expirience with flow says me that it's impossible to move types to libdef files for project-specific code.

Comment: @AlexSavin I have been fiddling around some more and i am experiencing the same. Libdefs are meant for third party code it seems.

Answer (score 0):

In our project, we use the following approach:

```
// @flow
export const square: SquareType = (value) => {
 return value * value;
}
```

So you can declare SquareType in the helpers.js file just above the function or you can move it to a separate file and import it then into helpers.js

Answer (score 0):

Many third-party modules don’t have types or only TypeScript types.

And libdefs need for one reason. To declare types for untyped modules!

More info: https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/